CapacitorHttp.post doesn't send JSON data on mobile device or simulator
I'm using Capacitor HTTP plugin to make a POST HTTP request like so:
  import { CapacitorHttp } from '@capacitor/core';

  async test() {
    const options = {
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      headers: { 
        'accept': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        "foo": "bar"
      },
    };
  
    const response = await CapacitorHttp.post(options);
    console.log(response.data);
  }

However the app sends nothing to the server. The request body is empty. Why?

Make sure you set Content-Type request header to application/json:
    const options = {
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        "foo": "bar"
      },
    };
  
    const response = await CapacitorHttp.post(options);
    console.log(response.data);

